# Non-English Unicode Support in Hugo Markdown Post

Tags: unicode, markdown, blogs, hugo

I have hugo installed in my VPS. I use it mainly for my personal blogs. I mainly write posts in english. But sometimes I need to write posts in non-english language (i.e. Bengali) unicode. 
But markdown file's post is not supporting non-enlish unicdoe character.
is there any way to write markdown file (.md) in unicode (non-english)?

**List of Steps to Reproduce issue:**

1) *Filename: Post.md*

```html
+++                                              
categories = [""]                      
comments = true                                  
date = "2019-08-16"                              
draft = false                                    
showpagemeta = true                              
showcomments = true                              
tags = ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]   
title = "some title"       
+++
```

2) Edit this file with Bengali language (unicode):

```html
+++                                              
categories = [""]                      
comments = true                                  
date = "2019-08-16"                              
draft = false                                    
showpagemeta = true                              
showcomments = true                              
tags = ["bengalitag1", "bengalitag2", "bengalitag3"]   
title = "বাংলা টাইটেল"       
+++     
আমি বাংলায় গান গাই।
(post in unicode Bengali)
```

3) Hugo serve working properly and site builds. But unicode posts showing no content, Completely blank Post (including blank title & tag)

any kind of help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: [Markdown is encoding agnostic.](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#character) Can you please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57523917/edit) and  write up a [detailed list of steps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to reproduce the faulty behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: Steps added with more details.

Comment: There's no English vs non-English Unicode. This question proves this, as StackOverflow uses Markdown and the HTML pages are UTF8 and yet, the text is just fine. How did you save the text file? If you *don't* save it using a Unicode encoding, eg UTF8 or UTF16, the text will get garbled. This has nothing to do with Markdown. Which editor did you use? Did you configure it to save files as UTF8?

Comment: Have you checked the HTML source to see what is actually generated? Are the generated HTML pages properly identified as UTF-8 (or some other appropriate Unicode encoding) in the HTML meta tags? Are they being served as UTF-8 by the server?

Comment: Issue solve after fixing file encoding. Editor used: VScode, Thanks...